# Datagridview virtualmode with heavy data load

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, datagridview

I want to display a "lot of heavy data" inside datagridview in virtual mode.

I use a buffer where I store n (2) pages of data, initially 2 first pages are stored in buffer. When the gridview is scrolled upto a row that does not exist in buffer i load the current new page and swap it with an old page.

To simulate loading heavy data from database into the buffer, I added this line:
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
as the result , as the buffer update itself the grid is frozen for this period of time.

Now, as I understand adding a thread won't help here because there is only 1 operation that happens only when scroll reaches unbuffered row.

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender, DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {

       e.Value = theBuffer.ReturnFromBuffer(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
//I check there if row index is in buffer and if not i update the buffer with new page and return the value

    }
```

So I am thinking about adding a "spinning wheel" animation above the gird when it happens.

I tried, to send event to form to show/hide the image within the method that updates the buffer:

```
if (ProgressEvent != null)
     ProgressEvent(true);

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

if (ProgressEvent != null)
     ProgressEvent(false);
```

and on form event handler set the visible property of the image, but the result was not as expected, i guess Sleep happened before event was handled, so the image didn't appear before the sleep.

Som I guess that a tread is still needed. But  can't figure when it sholud started and what should it do?

**Update:**

I tired the suggested background worker:
Inside the method that is beeing  called by  CellValueNeeded event, i check if the requested row is buffered, if not i start backgroundworker.

```
 if (!bgWorker.IsBusy) //otherwise worker will be started for every column of the row
 {
      bgWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
         {
           UpdateBuffer(rowIndex);                           
          };
       bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
 }
 return "null";
```

And this:

```
bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (IvalidateEvent != null)
        IvalidateEvent();  //send event to form, where invalidate the gridview  dataGridView1.Invalidate();
};
```

it works but there a few problems with that:
1) I got many dummy results in my grid, even if it's not for long - I don't like it much.
2)it even takes more time if I just left it as is, probably because backgroundworker consumes some time and because I actually invalidate grid and call CellValueNeeded event 2 times (first onem to start backgroundworkerm second time when it finishes it's work)!

Comment: invalidating the whole grid is a bit like "overkill" ... it will also repaint all cells that have correct values, instead of only those with dummies.  another approach to avoid dummy values while scrolling through the grid would be to react on the scrolling itself. try to fetch rows that are close to the displayed rows before they are requested, in that case the values will likely be there before CellNeedsValue requests them

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, CellNeedsValue buffers not only the needed row but a bunch of rows ahead. the only problem when I need to load new rows. I don't mind to freeze the grid, but animation must appear as it happens. without dummy values

Comment: when the datagridview raises cellvalueneeded you can specify a value to be shown in the cell. if you don't have that value, you can't specify it. so you have 2 options: 1) either provide a "loading"-message or nothing (empty string) , fill your buffer in an async operation and when the data is ready update the cell. or option 2) fill the buffer synchronously and return the desired value. of course option 2 will block the UI thread, so no loading animation, form repainting, or user interaction will be available (unless you do bad things like Application.DoEvents - that will be a pain to debug)

Comment: the problem with that is when I,for example, click on pagedown many times, so dummy value fills many rows (until data is loaded). for testing I use dataset as source and datatable that holds page in memory. Maybe other resources would work faster?

Comment: i don't think so ... try optimizing the loader process ... create a class that handles requests to the buffer that require to load data ... store such requests and when your worker thread runs, try to collect more than just one row (reduce the number of queries) ... when the worker has finished his job, have it look at the list of requests and continue using that worker instead of spawning new workers if ther's more to do... track the scroll event and make sure that the next and prevous X rows are in the buffer (so after scrolling the buffer can supply the value directly)

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, I do not load one row, i load page (about 50 rows) every time. and buffer holds 2 page where i update the far-most page with a new one. For  the spawning new workers (actually it the same worker that restarts every time if it's not busy)m what do you mean "have it look at the list of requests", the request come as soon as CellValueNeeded event needs a value that is not buffered

Comment: sorry if my english is too bad to explain this properly: lets say that you are displaying a page located somewhere in the middle of a large result ... the displayed page is in the buffer, so your DGV can get the cell values from there without delay. expand that scheme to the following: lets say currently the rows 500 to 550 are displayed -> hold the rows 450 to 600 in your buffer ... when the user scrolls 3 rows down, drop the rows 450 to 452 from your buffer, and request the buffering ot the rows 601 to 603 in the background

Comment: what i mean with "have it look at the list of requests": the position of the currently displayed rows in the result can tell you what rows are likely to be requested next ... request those rows to be loaded in the background BEFORE your CellValueNeeded handler tries to get them from the buffer ... store those requests somewhere, and reuse your background worker thread to process them instead of creating a new thread (get rid of thread startup delay)

Comment: ok, i thought about updating buffer without CellValueNeeded asking for that but: 1)what will trigger the background buffering? background worker can't just wait fo requests, it only works if there is somthing to do...2) what if user moves the scroll to the middle? no chance to buffer this in advance

Comment: requests should trigger background buffering. it can wait for requests: give your worker an endless loop that will only be interrupted when an exit flag is set. inside that loop let your worker thread wait for a WaitHandle. when you have placed requests in the list of the worker, release the WaitHandle. requests are generated when the user scrolls. also try to cancel pending requests that are no longer needed (will happen when the user is scrolling too fast) ... you can't buffer everything in advance, but you can try to anticipate what will be needed next

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you reach an unbuffered line, call your code to get the required data in a 2nd thread (new Thread, threadpool, backgroundworker ... choose one)

after this async operation has been started make the "loading..." control visible

(here you will probably want to disable parts of your UI until the operation is completed)

for now return an empty string or some other dummy value...

your async operation should get the desired data and then invoke another method the ui thread (call Invoke(...) on your Form's object)

the invoke call is needed to avoid cross-thread UI interaction

in the invoked method you should use the fetched data to populate your buffer, hide the "loading..." control, invalidate the corresponding row(s) or cell(s) (the datagridview has methods to do this) and last but not least reenable your UI if necessary

Comment: yes, i thought about it but there is problem that I'll try to explain:  there can be a situation while new thread loads to data into the buffer user can scroll the grid again and a new thread will start!! this will cause a lot of mess. I don't think that I want to lock the scroll.

Comment: And also,CellValueNeeded waits for it's value how can it use the thread? it won't wait for thread to complete

Comment: 1st: the waiting cellValueNeeded handler ... don't let it wait ... return a dummy value, eg. "loading...". and later when the async operation has finished and the data is in your buffer, invalidate the row/cell. that will raise CellValueNeeded again, and then you can get the real value. 2nd: to have only one worker at a time you could write a class that handles requests for data. when data is requested, and no data is currently fetched, start the thread. when data is currently fetched, enqueue the request ... at the end of your fetching process check for waiting requests ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, what do you mean by "invalidate the row/cell" . Alsom i do't think I can return dummy value, because it will put it inside the cell.

Comment: when a control (like a DataGridViewCell) needs to be redrawn you can invalidate it's client area, so the next time the UI thread gets into idle state it will redraw that area. usually you call Invalidate() on a control to trigger this. for a datagridview-cell/-row this is done from the datagridview-object (if i remember correctly the method is named InvalidateRow(...)/InvalidateCell(...)) in virtual mode the datagridview will raise CellValueNeeded before it can redraw a cell. so you have that dummy value in that cell while the data is fetched in the background, and then the real data appears

Comment: So after I finish loading data from thread I should call Invalidate? and what if I just start the animation from thread? (i'll start the above event via BeginInvoke)

Comment: after you finish loading data you should insert that data into your buffer, and invalidate the corresponding cell or the entire row.  be aware that you may not interact with a control from outside of your UI thread.  you need to invoke the UI thread to interact with controls